# why transaction receipt's root field is always "0x" in geth 1.7?

Tags: solidity, metropolis

I use geth 1.7 to set up a private network, my genesis config is [image]

this is my contract, the first transaction result is of enen(1,2); the second transaction result is of enen(0,2)
[image]

why the transaction receipt's root filed is always "0x" whether the transaction is successful or not?

Comment: This is *probably* related to EIP-98, which came in with Geth 1.7... https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/98

Comment: EIP-98 said "the intermediate state root parameter in the receipt should be set to a \x01 byte if the outermost code execution succeeded, or a zero byte if the outermost code execution failed."

Comment: In that case it sounds like geth isn't serializing it properly, to `"0x0"`.